# The results of Parse.Query.find is undefined in my cloud function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I'm a newbie who just started to use Parse for my casual mobile game.

I'm writing a cloud code with which client can request a deck purchase.
Since code is important to explain my problems, I moved my questions below the code.

I have the following classes :

```
    1. User :
        coin(Number)

    2. Deck :
        priceCoin(Number)
        nickname(String)

    3. User_Deck :
        userId(Pointer to User)
        deckId(Pointer to Deck)
```

Data of Classes and Client Request :

- User and Deck classes have one row for each, and the user request to purchase the deck.
- Parameter sent to cloud function is deck, which is the objectId of the Deck.

And this is the cloud function :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("req_purchase_deck", function(request, response) {
    var purchaseDeck;
    var deckQuery = new Parse.Query("Deck");
    deckQuery.get( request.params.deck, function(result) {
        purchaseDeck = result; // Q2 : is this valid in the scope of this function?
        var userHasQuery = new Parse.Query("User_Deck");
        userHasQuery.equalTo("userId", request.user);
        userHasQuery.equalTo("deckId", result);
        return userHasQuery.find();
    }).then( function( results ) { // Q1 : Why results undefined?
        if( results == null || results.length == 0 ) {
            var userCoin = request.user.get("coin");
            var priceCoin = purchaseDeck.get("priceCoin");
            if( userCoin >= priceCoin ) {
                console.log("/purchase made/" + userCoin + " - " + priceCoin + " = " + userCoin - priceCoin);
                request.user.set("coin", userCoin - priceCoin);
                return request.user.save();
            }
            else {
                return Parse.Promise.error("not enough coins");
            }
        }
        else {
            return Parse.Promise.error("already has deck");
        }
    }).then( function(result) {
        var newUserDeckObject = new Parse.Object("User_Deck");
        newUserDeckObject.set("userId", request.user);
        newUserDeckObject.set("deckId", purchaseDeck);
        console.log("/purchase deck added");
        return newUserDeckObject.save();
    }).then( function(result) {
        var returns = {};
        returns["userCoins"] = request.user.get("coin");
        returns["purchasedDeck"] = purchaseDeck.get("nickname");
        response.success(returns);
        console.log(request.user.username + "/purchase deck succeeded--/");
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

The result :
        already has deck // even though there is no rows at all in User_Deck class. And I found 'results' is undefined.

Question 1 : deckQuery was well made, but userDeckQuery results in undefined results : what is wrong with my code?
        I put a lot of logs to figure out why, but this was the only thing I found.

Question 2 : I'm cacheing deckQuery result to purchaseDeck, and is the object valid through out to the end of this cloud function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Q2: yeah, should be fine.  Q1: I don't see why this would hit the success block with undefined results.

Comment: @Fosco Thanks man for the second question's answer! :)

Comment: @Fosco, I realized why. I should have used either callback style - query( success:fn{}, error:fn{} )) or promise - query().then(successFn{}, errorFn{}). I'm not used to Java Script and Promise. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I realized why.
I used callback style return for my query and expected to get a result of promise style.
I marked with comment

```
Parse.Cloud.define("req_purchase_deck", function(request, response) {
    var purchaseDeck;
    var deckQuery = new Parse.Query("Deck");
    //deckQuery.get( request.params.deck, function(result) {
    deckQuery.get( request.params.deck ).then( function(result) { // Q1 solved.
        purchaseDeck = result; // Q2 : @Fosco answered that it's fine.
        var userHasQuery = new Parse.Query("User_Deck");
        userHasQuery.equalTo("userId", request.user);
        userHasQuery.equalTo("deckId", result);
        return userHasQuery.find();
    }).then( function( results ) {
        if( /*results == null ||*/results.length == 0 ) { // results never be null
            var userCoin = request.user.get("coin");
            var priceCoin = purchaseDeck.get("priceCoin");
            if( userCoin >= priceCoin ) {
                console.log("/purchase made/" + userCoin + " - " + priceCoin + " = " + userCoin - priceCoin);
                request.user.set("coin", userCoin - priceCoin);
                return request.user.save();
            }
            else {
                return Parse.Promise.error("not enough coins");
            }
        }
        else {
            return Parse.Promise.error("already has deck");
        }
    }).then( function(result) {
        var newUserDeckObject = new Parse.Object("User_Deck");
        newUserDeckObject.set("userId", request.user);
        newUserDeckObject.set("deckId", purchaseDeck);
        console.log("/purchase deck added");
        return newUserDeckObject.save();
    }).then( function(result) {
        var returns = {};
        returns["userCoins"] = request.user.get("coin");
        returns["purchasedDeck"] = purchaseDeck.get("nickname");
        response.success(returns);
        console.log(request.user.username + "/purchase deck succeeded--/");
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

now result is "not enough coin"